# How to get count of categories within column from time series resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm new to data frames and am struggling to figure out how to accomplish the following:

I have a dataframe already as a time series like so:

```
timestamp             source                        
2017-06-18 10:43:54    two
2017-06-20 03:38:23    three
2017-06-18 07:37:02    one
2017-06-07 16:49:51    two
2017-06-15 22:36:10    two
2017-06-07 16:49:51    two
2017-06-18 22:36:10    two
```

I am trying to 1) resample into daily and 2) get a % of each category for that day.  Like so:

```
timestamp      One    Two  Three                    
2017-06-18     33%    66%    0%
2017-06-20     0%     0%    100%
2017-06-07     0%    100%    0%
2017-06-15     0%    100%    0%
```

I can accomplish basic things like, get a count of 'source' resampled to daily, but it doesn't break it down into categories.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you show the code you have managed to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `groupby` + `value_counts` + `unstack`

```
(df.groupby(df.timestamp.dt.date).source.value_counts(normalize=True)*100).unstack().fillna(0)

source            one  three         two
timestamp                               
2017-06-07   0.000000    0.0  100.000000
2017-06-15   0.000000    0.0  100.000000
2017-06-18  33.333333    0.0   66.666667
2017-06-20   0.000000  100.0    0.000000
```

---

#### `pivot_table`

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=df.timestamp.dt.date, columns='source', aggfunc='size')
df2 = df2.divide(df2.sum(1), axis=0).fillna(0)*100
```

#### `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.timestamp.dt.date, df.source, normalize='index')*100
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped clear some things up I was doing wrong.  Also I was mostly trying with 'resample'.

Comment: @Frankie since you only seem to want days in your output which appear in your original table, I think `groupby` is more appropriate. Resample will give you empty days in between, plus not sure it works easily for this type of calculation.

Comment: Or alternatively: `df.pivot_table(index=df.timestamp.dt.date, columns='source', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0).apply(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum(), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

to_period + value_counts can help!

```
date    winlose
0   2020-01-17  -1
1   2020-01-28  0
2   2020-02-06  0
3   2020-02-20  1
4   2020-02-21  1
```

> df.to_period('M').groupby('date')['winlose'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)
> shold be another option

```
winlose -1  0   1
date            
2020-01 1.0 1.0 0.0
2020-02 0.0 2.0 2.0
2020-03 0.0 0.0 1.0
2020-04 1.0 1.0 1.0
2020-05 1.0 3.0 0.0
2020-06 0.0 2.0 1.0
2020-07 1.0 3.0 0.0
2020-08 1.0 1.0 1.0
2020-09 1.0 3.0 0.0
2020-10 1.0 1.0 0.0
2020-11 0.0 1.0 0.0
2020-12 2.0 3.0 1.0
```