# Getting percentage for each column after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns `A` and `B`. The column `B` contains three categories `X`, `Y`, 'Z'. I need to check the how much percentage is a particular value for each group in A. Here is how the dataframe looks like:

```
  A   B
  AA  X 
  BB  Y
  CC  Z
  AA  Y
  AA  Y
  BB  Z 
  ..  ..
```

Now I want to plot a stacked plot but it should be a percentage based stacked plot and not just count based for each category in `B` corresponding to a group in `A`. Here is what I did so far:

`df.groupby(['A'])['B'].value_counts().unstack()` which gives me this

```
B   X    Y      Z
A           
AA  65   666    5
BB  123  475    6
CC  267  1337   40
```

Now I want to divide each column by the sum of it's corresponding row  like for first row `(65/(65+666+5), 666/(65+666+5), 5/(65+666+5),)`and plot the results as stacked bar plot.
Can someone please help?

Comment: A similar question was asked [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148446/how-to-get-count-of-categories-within-column-from-time-series-resample). Just add `normalize=True` as an argument to `value_counts`

Comment: Yeah, foolish me. It was that easy. Thanks Alloz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the row-wise sum and divide along the axis something like this:

```
freq_df = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].value_counts().unstack()
pct_df = freq_df.divide(freq_df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
```

And then to plot that you should simply be able to use

```
pct_df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works well.

Step 1. Apply groupby

Step 2. Use value_count

Step 3. Use unstack

Step 4. Multiply with 100 and apply a round function.

Step 5. Apply a fillna method to fill 0 for empty values

Here is the code

```
df.groupby(['A'])['B']\
   .value_counts(normalize=True)\
   .unstack()\
   .mul(100)\
   .round(2)\
   .fillna(0)
```

Or you can alternatively use the crosstab method

Step 1. Use crosstab

Step 2. Apply a lambda function.

```
pd.crosstab(df["A"], df["B"])\
.apply(lambda x: round(x / x.sum() * 100, 2), axis = 1)
```